# How do you test a file generator in a rails 5 gem with rspec

Tags: rspec, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm completely new to testing, but I want to learn and I am having trouble with using Rspec to test a gem I created. The gem just creates a new folder with two files in a desired location. How do I test that the files were created and in the proper location?

I used bundler to create the gem and have `spec.add_development_dependency "rspec", "~> 3.0"` in my gemspec file and currently my spec folder contains `my_gemname.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`. Do I need to create a `spec/dummy` and install a full app for rspec to test against? and how do you write a test in rspec to test if a file was generated?

so my three questions: 
1. How do I test that the files were created and in the proper location? 
2. Do I need to create a `spec/dummy` and install a full app for rspec to test against? 
3. How do you write a test in rspec to test if a file was generated? 
4. Or what is the best free resource for learning Rspec? the best paid option?

I'm using rails 5.1.2 with --webpack=react if this helps at all.